# How to edit message in Telegram using Telethon?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I've already learnt how to edit the message text form this https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telethon.html#telethon.telegram_client.TelegramClient.edit_message.
But how to change photos or some other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking out an unofficial version of the documentation which is very out of date. The official version is [`TelegramClient.edit_message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.edit_message), which showcases the `file` parameter:

```py
await client.edit_message(chat, msg_id, file='example.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
messageMini = await client.get_messages(my_channel, ids=14)
ficheroMini = messageMini.file
print(messageMini.text) #I see the caption of the image of message 14 in channel
    
texto = ' random text ' #I must change text every time casue... telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MessageNotModifiedError: Content of the message was not modified (caused by EditMessageRequest)
await client.edit_message(my_channel, mid, texto, file=ficheroMini) #no error: change the caption, but not the image
#await client.edit_message(my_channel, mid, file='puppy.jpg') #it works: replace image
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).